# Flutter rotate the screen

Tags: android, flutter, rotation, screen

```
void _rotateScreen() {
    final currentOrientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;

    if (currentOrientation == Orientation.portrait) {
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
        DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
      ]);
    } else {
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
        DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      ]);
    }
    setState(() {});
  }
```

when i click the button screen is rotating down but if screen is down its not come again portrait up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Flutter, you can use the `MediaQuery` class to get the current `orientation` of the device. However, this will only tell you if the device is in `portrait` or `landscape` mode, not the specific orientation (**up**, **down**, **left**, **right**).

Since you are checking if the `currentOrientation == Orientation.portrait` every time it returns the same value, so the result is the same. Instead of that condition, I think you can:

1. use the [native_device_orientation](https://pub.dev/packages/native_device_orientation) package and do it like what you are doing.

or

2. You can set it manually using a boolean value and set a default (*up* or *down*). On button click, rotate the screen. Something like:

```dart
bool isUp = false;

setPortraitUp() {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  ]);
  isUp = true;
}

setPortraitDown() {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
  isUp = false;
}

void _rotateScreen() {
  if (isUp) {
    setPortraitDown();
  } else {
    setPortraitUp();
  }
  setState(() {});
}
```

And you can set the default (*up* or *down*) on `initState`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your default screen orientation in the main.dart like so:

```
Future main() async {
   WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding = 
         WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
  [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);
```

when you need an other orientation on a specific screen (StatefulWidget) use this in your init method:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
     super.initState();
     SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
       DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
       DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    ]);
  _initGame();
 }
```

inside the on dispose method you can set the orientation back, like this:

```
  @override
  dispose() {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
     DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
     DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
  super.dispose();
  }
```